# How to disable iframe border on mobile safari?

Tags: css

Seems like some other people have had this same problem too.

On the contact form at the bottom of: http://ntcc.johnmbjerke.com the iframe being loaded via wufoo has a small grey border (only on iOS safari) that won't go away no matter what I've tried in css. Ideas?

Screenshot here: http://d.pr/i/udQa

Comment: same problem! did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

try and add a css rule - `overflow: hidden;`
worked for me at least.